# Deploying .net webapplications

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I have a local .net webapplication which needs to be run every time to see the output . Instead of that can i deploy it on the local host server...so that through url i can see the output.

Can you please suggest how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you want to deploy it in creating a virtual directory using IIS.

Read this if you are using IIS 6.0:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172138

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5adfcce1-030d-45b8-997c-bdbfa08ea459.mspx?mfr=true